# How to create a .bat file for launching Edge in IE Mode, with URLs added?

Tags: batch-file, internet-explorer, uipath

I'm running an RPA process (UiPath) which requires a website to be open in Edge, in Internet Explorer Mode (IE Mode). I'd like to just run a .bat file which does this for each machine I deploy on.

I have no experience of .bat files (apologies!) but do know how to run them from my IDE (UiPath Studio).

Thank you!

Comment: I've done something similar using a batch HTA hybrid which creates an instance of Internet Explorer, if you are open to just skipping Edge. You can script Internet Explorer as an ActiveXObject [Scripting an Internet Explorer window](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141020-00/?p=43813)

Comment: Regardless of your inexperience with batch files, the very minimum you should have done, is researched whether Microsoft Edge accepts command line arguments, and if so, which arguments are required for your specific task. If they are accepted, and you determine what those are then all a batch file would contain was ```@Start "AnyTitle" msedge.exe ArgumentsHere```. _If it helps, generally Edge should accept most of the commandline arguments attributed to chromium browsers_. This site is a resource, it is not where you post a set of requirements, and expect someone to do it for you.

Comment: I do not think there is currently an IE Mode command line argument. If you have the option at your organization, you may want to roll out an [IE Mode Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-internet-explorer-integration)

Comment: @Compo thanks, that helps. Clearly, I spent my time Googling the wrong things. Didn't know about command line arguments. Everyone starts somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Qwerty's opinion. There's no such IE mode command line argument at present. The recommended way to configure Edge IE mode is using group policies:

1. [Configure Internet Explorer integration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-internet-explorer-integration)
2. [Use the Enterprise Mode IE website list (Internet Explorer)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-using-the-use-the-enterprise-mode-ie-website-list-policy) or [Configure the Enterprise Mode Site List (Microsoft Edge, version 78 or later)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-using-the-configure-the-enterprise-mode-site-list-policy)

After you configure the policies correctly for the domain, each machine in the domain will open the specific sites in Edge IE mode automatically.